# onchange not firing when date of input type="date" is clear as first action

Tags: javascript, onchange

I have a `type="date"` input that onchange fires some JS. My problem is that if you want to clear the date with the "cross button" on the right of the input tag, it will not fire the `onchange` event, unless you have previously changed the value. It seems really weird to me. My question: can I fire JS when my first action is clicking the "cross button" that delete the date?

I'm using Firefox 58.0.1

**Edit:** Now if working as expected (sept 2020, Firefox 80.0.1)

```js
function myFunction(IdTag) {
var x = document.getElementById(IdTag).value;
    alert('The new value is: '+x);
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="MyID" value="2018-02-06" onchange="myFunction('MyID');">
```

Comment: Works in the code snippet?

Comment: Same problem in the code snippet. I've been checking. Firefox: the  problem reported in the question, Chrome: no problem, IE: do not have the "delete date" as FF and Chrome.

Comment: It is hard to get the same experience cross browser with the native date input field. You can take a look at the MDN docs for it regarding cross browser support. You could try using a third party plugin too to get the same experience across browsers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Handling_browser_support

Comment: @AndrewLohr yes, you are right. Date input is rather incipient. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me.

I created an html file with this content:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <input type="date" id="MyID" value="2018-02-06" onchange="myFunction('MyID');">
    <script>
      function myFunction(IdTag) {
        var x = document.getElementById(IdTag).value;
        alert('The new value is: '+x);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the event fired and also cleared the date (which was set to MM/DD/YYYY).

Make sure you're not seeing any errors in the Developer Tools.

Comment: In firefox, the input field shows the date and a button (inside the input, at right) for clearing the input. That button do not fire the `onchange` event if is the first action performed. Although it works OK in Chrome. My version of IE do not have said button.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue as well (FF 64.0.1 on Linux) and I solved it by utilising the 'mousedown' event.

Essentially when the mousedown event triggers set up a timer that will manually trigger the onchange on your date input after a certain time, I found 500ms was sufficient for my use case.

I am using jQuery and got it to work, the process should be fairly similar for native JS:

```
$('input[name="start_date"]').on('mousedown',function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){ $($this).trigger('change'); }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and after some research i figured out that there is already a unconfirmed bug Report [at Mozilla Bugtracker](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1446722).

I am using jQuery and my solution was to call focus and blur after binding the even

```
$('#datefield').on('change', someFunction).focus().blur();
```

because the bug only appears if someone clicks on the reset button before giving the input the focus. By set and remove the focus to the input, the user does not recognize anything and the bug is bypassed.